# react-native-signature-capture Android - Unable to send image to api as formdata

Tags: android, react-native, webapi

I've a react app that use react-native-signature-capture component (https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture) to acquire user signature.
After many attempts I was able to save the file with the signature in the camera roll of my android device.
Now I should send the file to a webapi that requires formdata as input but I can't find the way to do it.

I'm using android 11

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code example**

```
const formdata = new FormData();

const signature = {
  uri: result.pathName, // File path uri you get from signature library
  type: 'image/jpeg', // image type
  name: 'signature.jpg', // name of the image
};

formdata.append("signature", signature);
    
fetch('YOUR API URL', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      body: formdata,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('image uploaded');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

**I hope this helps you out.**

Comment: Thank you!
Another question: can I possibly send base64 as multipart / form-data? I have problems reading the files from the android (due to privacy restriction on internal memory) roll so I thought not to save the signature file but to use the base64

Comment: Why you are saving files to internal memory when the signature library already providing the Uri of the image. just send that path to your api. If you want to use base64 then you have to parse the image into base64 using RNFS library and then send that to the api.